# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on systems with AMD APUs: Split screens, or even outright failure to see anything!

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

I just finished building my own PC and I would like to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in a dual-boot with my already-installed Windows 10.

Here's an example of a split-screen in BIOS mode. In UEFI mode, you can't see anything at all!

[image: Since I can't really describe what happens, so here's an image.]

Needless to say, I'm glad I picked "Try Ubuntu". Apparently there are some issues with AMD APUs / recent kernels? I'm running a Ryzen 5 2400G and HDMI out through the motherboard.

https://community.amd.com/thread/228018

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This split screen problem could be solved with a simple trick. You insert your usb drive, start the PC, when the GRUB2 screen shows up press E on your keyboard (no upper case). A black screen with set parameters will open. Find the line *linux/boot* ending with *quiet splash*. Insert *nomodeset* before *quiet splash*. Then press Ctrl-x or F10 to start. You should have a full screen for your installation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try again. Give me a bit and I'll get back to this thread.

Comment: Works! Had to edit grub config even after install to persistently insert that.

Terminal: `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Fifth real line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"`

Comment: (Off-topic: "splash" (the four? red dot splash screen) was just a nuisance. It's most useful purpose was to point me to the setting where `nomodeset` needed to be inserted. The words `quiet splash` can be omitted for a clean yet informative boot.)

Comment: Ultimately, I jumped to a later kernel (4.18.8 happened to be available) and then I could remove the "nomodeset" and then things worked that didn't before (e.g. flux). UKUU made this very easy:
https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/